# Avoid using merge fields in validation formulas

Tags: validation-rule, bestpractice

So I've just come across this as part of Salesforce [best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_validation_rules_tips.htm&type=5) for validation rules.

> Avoid using the **IsClosed** or **IsWon** opportunity merge fields in validation formulas. Instead, use the ISPICKVAL function to determine if the Stage contains the appropriate value. For example, this validation formula makes a custom Project Start Date field required whenever the Stage is Closed Won. e.g.
> `AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"), ISBLANK(Project_Start_Date__c))`

I've always tended to use "IsWon" or "IsClosed" as it is cleaner than referencing multiple closed or won stages (which may change in the future).

Does anyone have an idea what the reason against using these "merge" fields are?

Comment: I believe the answer is that as these are formula fields, they won't have the values you expect if the transaction involves transitioning from a non-won state to a won state. They work perfectly well, for example, if Opportunity is already Won and you want to prevent other edits; they also work great as filters in reports and listviews. Some discussion on this [here](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/steven-trumble_salesforce-formulas-activity-7107715963856244736-3zGq/). You can run your own experiments to confirm.

Comment: @cropredy You are correct; calculated values are loaded only when a record load occurs, which happens twice in the transaction lifecycle.

Comment: That's weird. It seems that IsWon/IsClosed works correctly now. As a result, my answer wasn't correct, so I've removed it. I have two theories why they don't recommend using those flags: (1) an administrator might be surprised later when they add a new closed/won state and get the validation error, or (2) the documentation is simply outdated even though they fixed the problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- my bet is on #2

Comment: thanks [tag:sfdcfox] [tag:cropredy]